# Verilog: Posedge sensitivity vs. If statement in Always block

Tags: fpga, verilog, timing, vivado, negative

I have recently completed a design that had run into timing issues (negative slack).  The modules that were found to be troublesome, from the timing reports generated in Vivado 2017.4, are these modules that are used to calculate some synchronous outputs.  A clock, reset, and enable (en) signal are provided as inputs.  The modules that had these issues were previously implemented as shown below:

```
always @ (clk, rst) begin
     if (rst) begin
          ...
          ...
     end
     else if (clk & en) begin
          ...
          ...
     end
end
```

A coworker suggested that the "code is creating latches for the pipeline segments, instead of clocked flip flops".  Following his suggestions I changed the modules to what is shown below.

```
always @ (posedge clk, posedge rst) begin
     if (rst) begin
          ...
          ...
     end
     else if (en) begin
          ...
          ...
     end
end
```

This seems to have resolved the negative slack coming from these modules, but I am curious to know why this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A coworker suggested that the "code is creating latches for the pipeline segments, instead of clocked flip flops".

The two code segments are totally different.
The first is combinatorial logic, the second is a register.

The behavior of the two is also total different.
In the first what you call a 'clk' is *not* giving you the behavior of a real clock at all, it is just a signal<sup>*</sup>. 
From the first code you can get gates or latches, but *not* registers. 
In the code section you should use blocking `=` assignments.

The second format should produce registers with an asynchronous positive reset.
In the code section you should use non-blocking `<=` assignments.

<sup>*</sup><sub>(That was so unusual that it caused my first, wrong, answer)</sub>

---

> I'm just having a hard time seeing why this would be the root of a timing issue.

As you are saying you get negative slack, I assume some other parts of the circuit does have registers in them.
The logic from the first parts of the code has NO registers. It is just one huge combinatorial 'blob'.

> my original thinking was that the if-statements would help implement the sequential behavior

No, an `if` statement produces only multiplexers which are combinatorial again.

Comment: The project still ran through the Synthesis, Implementation, and Generate Bitstream.  I am assuming that some inference was made by Vivado while going through this process then?

Comment: I can see how the first is interpreted as combinatorial, but my original thinking was that the if-statements would help implement the sequential behavior that I intended to have.  The second code segment seems to be better defined, I guess I'm just having a hard time seeing why this would be the root of a timing issue.

Comment: Great, that makes a lot of sense now.  Especially the 'blob' part of the explanation, thank you for the help.  I guess I have a pretty simple work around to implement and a habit to start when coding.

Comment: @Oldfart, I don't see how it's purely combinatorial. If you have an `x = y` inside there, then you have a case where `x` changes, but only when an event happens on `clk` or `rst`.  I don't think there's combinatorial logic that can do that. (But I also don't think there are latches that can do it either, so it's hard to say what will really happen)

Comment: @ThePhoton No, the crux is all synthesis tools ignore the sensitivity list. The biggest danger is that you simulation and you actual hardware do no longer match. It is the reason why you should use `always @( *)` or `always_comb` for any RTL code.

Comment: @Oldfart, if you ignore the sensitivity list, then OP's two example codes are identical.

Comment: If I actually want a latch, I should write `always @(clk or y) begin if(clk) x = y; end`, right? If I use `always @(*)` do I still get a latch, or do I get combinatorial logic?

Comment: It is rather complex: the sensitivity list is scanned with the rest of the code to see if it adheres to the syntax which can produces a register. In that case register(s) comes out. If the syntax adheres to combinatorial code the sensitivity list is ignored and combinatorial logic comes out. You can write code which is neither combinatorial nor registers in which case the tool gives an error. That is also the reason why you have to follow a **strict** coding syntax if you want registers.

Comment: Both of your codes `always @(clk or y)` or `always @(*)` produce a latch. I assume that is the reason why  many in HDL design see a latch as a combinatorial circuit.